# php mysql query help for category

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------+--------+------+
| id |         thesis_title          | cat_id | status | year |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+--------+------+
| 10 | Project Award - 2014          | 1,2    | C      | 2014 |
| 11 | Project Award - 2015          | 1,2    | C      | 2015 |
| 12 | Research Award for PhD - 2015 | 3      | A      | 2015 |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+--------+------+
```

Table 2

```
+----+--------------------------+---------+
| id |         category         | Status  |
+----+--------------------------+---------+
|  1 | Undergraduate Course(UG) |       1 |
|  2 | Postgraduate Course(PG)  |       1 |
|  3 | PhD                      |       1 |
+----+--------------------------+---------+
```

I have two tables as above.

I want to select categories of Table 2 from Table 1, if the Status is C (Closed)

`for ex:Table 1 contains cat_id 1,2(string separated by commas` and the Table 2 contains these as id:1,2,3, and the categories.

So I want to select the respective categories from Table 2 for cat_id of Table 1.

Comment: you named your table `Table 1` ?

Comment: Fix your data layout so you are not storing category ids in a comma separated list.

Comment: What do you want all data of Table 1 or Table2

Comment: This feels like a homework question

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question.... (you need categories name which related to closed project).

1. select all categories from table 1 which has status C.
2. union all categories_id (remove duplicates) and create a list comma separated.
3. select category name from table 2 where id in generated list.

"select category from table 2 where id in ('1', '2')";

Edit:

1:  select closed categories.

```js
$count = 0;
    
    $cat_list = "";
                                
    $qry = "select cat_id from table 1 where status = 'C'";
    
    $fetch = mysql_query($qry);
            
     while($row = mysql_query($fetch)){ 
    
      $count++;
      
      if($count == 1){$cat_list .= $row['cat_id'];}
      
      else{$cat_list .= ", ".$row['cat_id'];}
    
    } 
    
    $cat_list = array_unique(explode(",",  str_replace(" ", "", $cat_list)));
    
    $cat_list = "'".implode("','", $cat_list)."'";
```

2: query

```js
$qry = "select category from table 2 where id in (".$cat_list.")";
```

Comment: yes, exactly I need the same result But here id in ("1",'2') is not static. some time it will be 1,2,3,4... etc. I need the dynamic query. That is, result set of cat_id of Table 1, which select category of Table 2.

Comment: <pre>can you modify these code to  db_query instead of mysql_query beacuse connection error is existing   .The one porting of the old code is writen as  <label class="usr_name" for="first_name">Category</label>
  <?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM thesis_category";
  $db->setQuery($sql);  
  $result = $db->loadAssocList();
  ?>
  <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"><?php echo $res['category']; ?></option> 
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  ?>  </pre>